# android: multi language database issue

Tags: android, sqlite, multilingual

world! I am developing an Android project for my Android course at university. I am creating an app about my country. So a user will be able to view our national food, instruments etc. I cannot figure out a good approach for creating a table so that it supports multi languages in android SQLite. My solution for food table:

**ID** Primary key

**Food_name-def** VARCHAR(100)

**Food-name-ru** VARCHAR(100)

**Food-desc-def** TEXT

**Food-desc-ru** TEXT.

Is this a good approach for suuporting multi languages for each table(food, instruments etc)?

Answer (score 0):

I would create an extra table for each translatable object. The approach of creating distinct columns is not a good approach for this case.

In your case:

```
Food:
    ID
    Food_name (language neutral version)
    Food_desc (language neutral version)

FoodTrans:
    FoodID
    Food_name
    Food_desc
    Language
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply!